# Change rollover text color to green in navbar

Tags: html, css

I'm not a client developer and have spent hours doing something I'm sure many of you can do in seconds.

I have the following code. I want to change the link color to `green` on rollover. Nothing I'm trying is working; the rollover color is consistently white. What do I need to do?

```css
.nav>li>a:hover,
.nav>li>a:focus {
  background-color: #EF92A5;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color: white; border-color:white;">
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" style="background-color:white; border-color:white;">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="background-color:white; border-color: white;">
      <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Records" asp-action="Index">Home</a></li>
      <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="About">About</a></li>
      <li><a asp-controller="Records" asp-action="Create">Contribute</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You had a few small problems.

1. You were closing the tag of the `nav` tag you created on the opening
   tag. You needed to remove the slash "/".
2. You had your "rollover"
   color set to a red hex value.

Here is a jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/tgk2x7bz/

Comment: The code working in jsfiddle, but not in the browser (Chrome).

Comment: @C.H. I just tried the code on Chrome and it seems fine. I'm not sure what exactly is wrong unless maybe you provide more details or have something up on the console.

Answer (score 0):

Can't add a comment yet, so I'm posting this as an answer.

Currently, what you have works although #EF92A5 is not green. [See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rxcp0c7n/)

In your nav element, remove the ending /:

Change

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color: white; border-color:white;" />
```

to

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color: white; border-color:white;">
```